# Encoding of /proc/<pid>/cmdline files

Tags: proc, character-encoding

I am thinking about working with the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` files, but I couldn't find any documentation about the file encoding. The only piece of information I could find is located in the man page:

```
 /proc/[pid]/cmdline
    This holds the complete command line for the process, unless the process is a zombie.  In the  latter
    case, there is nothing in this file: that is, a read on this file will return 0 characters.  The com‐
    mand-line arguments appear in this file as a set of strings separated by null bytes  ('\0'),  with  a
    further null byte after the last string.
```

What is the encoding of the cmdline file?

Comment: That seems like pretty complete documentation on the encoding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The command-line arguments appear in this file as a set of strings separated by null bytes  ('\0'),  with  a further null byte after the last string.

It is all you need. You have got command and its arguments separated by null  byte `\0`. Encoding of the characters is based on the `locale`, but it should not really matter.

Do you have some specific example where you need help?

Comment: I think I need to understand "why it should not really matter" as I am probably missing something here. Can the cmdline only consist of ASCII characters?

Comment: Yes. It should not matter, because the command line usually contains only ASCII. And if not, you have `locale` (`LANG` variable is in `/proc/<pid>/environ`).

Comment: @BenR It's arbitrary non-null bytes exactly as provided when launching the program. It may not be text at all.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: Now it gets interesting! :) Do you have any pointers / man pages that I could use to read up on this topic? I was under the assumption that a cmdline needs to be a character sequence.

Comment: Everything is bytes. Otherwise you'd have files you could never refer to.