# Chinese Characters in One of a File

Tags: linux-mint, proc, init

I have found some chinese characters in one of a file on my linux mint 20.1
File - `/proc/1/cmdline`
Chinese Characters - `猯楢⽮湩瑩猀汰獡h`

But when i open same file in terminal using `less` command, it shows : `/sbin/init^@splash^@`

Is this normal or is there anything to worry about in terms of security?

Comment: Related to, if not duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526487/ps-axf-shows-sbin-init-splash-for-pid1 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519250/splash-in-pid-1

Comment: So, There's no problem?? in GUI text editors it shows chinese characters.

Comment: What GUI text editors, exactly? If they do that by default, and it's not some kind of trick obtained by tweaking their settings, you can safely report it as a bug.

Comment: @user414777 Since the data contains nul bytes, I'm assuming the editor realizes it's not a file in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding and starts cycling through the available encoding until it finds one that "make sense" to it. This is IMHO a _relatively_ useful heuristic that might do the right thing in most situations, possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the nul-terminated strings `/sbin/init` and `splash`, and convert them *from* the UCS-2LE (or UNICODELITTLE, or UCS-2-INTERNAL) encoding using `iconv`, you get

```
$ printf '/sbin/init\0splash\0' | iconv -f UCS-2LE
猯楢⽮湩瑩猀汰獡h
```

The output from `less` is more correct. The `less` utility shows nul bytes (`\0`) as `^@`.

Conclusion: The "Chinese text" that you are seeing is  due to your editor determining that the data is encoded as UCS-2LE (for whatever reason).  It is not actually Chinese but simply the two nul-terminated strings `/sbin/init` and `splash`.

There is nothing you need to worry about.

For more information about `/sbin/init splash` see:

- [ps axf shows "/sbin/init splash" for PID1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526487/ps-axf-shows-sbin-init-splash-for-pid1)
- [Splash in PID =1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519250/splash-in-pid-1)

Additionally, you should not expect a text editor to be able to correctly understand the contents of the virtual file `/proc/1/cmdline` as it's not a text file.  This is probably why your text editor tried to determine the file's encoding, but failed to do so correctly.

See: [Encoding of /proc/<pid>/cmdline files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258478/encoding-of-proc-pid-cmdline-files)

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned few new things due to this.